# Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I have a set of vb.net classes and functions that heavily rely on the

```
DateAndTime
```

available in the

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

namespace.

Anyone knows if exists a "conversion table" for properties or methods somewhere (it seems SO doesn't)?

I would definitely like to avoid the need to reference VisualBasic.dll or start a trial and error process of figuring out the conversions if these are already done somewhere.

Thank you!

Comment: Why the reluctance to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`? It's a normal .NET assembly.

Comment: well, long story short, is to "not encourage" the use of legacy code. The reason why we have methods that use DateAndTime is because of an old VB6 application that has been translated to vb.net. If legacy code was written properly (i.e. not a spaghetti fiesta) it would be another story. I agree, a reference would solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any such conversion table.

The process of working out the equivalents shouldn't be too onerous, as you can decompile the DateAndTime class with Reflector or ILSpy.

Most are very straightforward (Date/Time arithmetic etc), and for the rest, most of the complexity is only needed to achieve backward compatibility for VB6.

For example `DateSerial(int year, int month, int day)` treats negative years as relative to the current date, and uses a calendar to convert 2-digit years to 4-digit years.  If your app isn't making use of this, you can replace by a `DateTime` constructor.

Comment: Joe's suggestion is great. Just use Reflector to grab the functions from `DateAndTime` and implement them in your own static class (if they are inside a Module)